# Can't install root-system-bin

Tags: apt, software-installation

Im using Ubuntu 13.0.4 and have tried getting updates via the command line ..no joy
Latest issue is trying to install Root

```
sudo apt-get install root-system-bin
Getting message
Reading package lists ... Error!
E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status-open (2: No such file or directory)
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

From http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2078996

But when I get to second line I get:-

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock-open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

Comment: Try `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock-open`

Comment: You sure it says `/var/lib/dpkg/status-open`?

Answer (score -2):

Look at your source list to make sure the web address is correct for all repository's.

-Open Software Sources and see if your repository list are displayed correctly. Are the repositories enabled?

-Run this command,

grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list

If you don't have the correct sources set up you can always establish new ones from the following website,
 http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Hope this points you in the right direction.